# Remove Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017 with a Bean

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a issue with MongoDB log, I need to remove this logh with a viriable on YAML, but this variable will beeing injected only manually.

```
2023-01-13 14:03:40.620  INFO 11124 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:180) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:193) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:157) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:107) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    ... 4 common frames omitted
```

I'm try to create a Class of configuration:

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureBefore(value = MongoAutoConfiguration.class)
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "${mock-server.data.persist-type}", value = "DataType", matchIfMissing = true)
public class MongoDBConfig {
```

and this is a variable on the yaml:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3aK6.png)

I'm try to you an class configuration to create a Bean method to exclude mongoDB as image when do not exist a variable like "DataType" like a image.